# Use Jquery trigger method for links

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, eventtrigger

Here is my sample http://jsfiddle.net/RaQtg/4/ I want to redirect my page to another URL by pressing G key, But I couden't trigger click function.

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.trigger()` like `.click()` can only work if you defined an event handler using `.bind()`(or `.live()`or `.on()` and all shortcuts available) methods.

try instead

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 103) //G key is pressed
    {
       alert("g key is pressed");
       location.href = $('mylink').attr('href');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like:

```
window.location = $('.mylink').attr('href');
```

If you have more than one item with the class `mylink`, the first one will always be used

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for the key g

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(evt) {

    if (evt.keyCode == 71) //G key is pressed
    {
        window.location = "http://"+$('.mylink').attr("href");

    }

});
```

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/yDsC8/

Comment: It works fine, thanks but I wonder whats wrong with trigger function?

Comment: `.trigger()` triggers a specific event bound to the link. If you do not have a function bound to an item's `keyup` event, you cannot trigger said `keyup` event..